# Vue - <head> elements appearing inside <body>

Tags: html, vue.js

Using Vue as the frontend and Django as the backend. I am serving the production version of `npm run build` via django. `index.html` is automatically generated. However, the `<head>` elements are inside of `<body>`. I tried a few articles and sees no difference.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
    <head>
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="" />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
        <!--[if IE]><link rel="icon" href="/static/favicon.ico"/><![endif]-->
        <title></title>

        manifests / css / app.js omitted

    </head>
    <body style="background-color: #131516;">
        <noscript
            ><strong
                >We're sorry but quicktrack doesn't work properly without
                JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong
            ></noscript
        >
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script src="/static/js/chunk-vendors.3aa94991.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/app.40e1aa2a.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

but when visiting the site  [this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVmsE.png)

Reading some other stackoverflow questions I found that this could be encoding issue.

`file -i index.html` shows `charset=us-ascii`.

I tried digging around webpack looking for encoding but I couldn't find one.

How should I go about fixing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not an encoding issue. It's a parsing issue. The HTML parser knows that the `</html>` and `<body>` tags (among others) are optional, and it knows that input elements go in the body, so when it sees the `<input type="hidden" ...>` tag, it assumes that the head element is complete and the body element has started. So it puts the input element and all following elements in the body.

It ignores the `</html>` and `<body>` tags when it eventually sees them, except that it merges the style attribute from the `<body>` tag on to the body element that it created earlier.

To fix, move the `<input type="hidden" ...>` tag to immediately after the `<body>` tag.